# NameError: name 'event' is not defined in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, nameerror

I'm writing a code in Python using tkinter to get a value from a combo box, after that I use this value in click event of a button. But when I run this code I got this error

"NameError: name 'event' is not defined"

My code is like this

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *    
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

font = FontProperties()
font.set_family('serif')
font.set_name('Times New Roman')
font.set_style('normal')  

    
window = Tk()
 
window.title("CCE Tool")
 
tab_control = Notebook(window) 

tab1 = Frame(tab_control) 
tab2 = Frame(tab_control)
 
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Regional') 
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Plot')

Filee_Tab1=Entry(tab1 ,width=70 , text='Enter adress of database')
Filee_Tab1.grid(column=1, row=0) 
 
lbl1_Tab1 = Label(tab1, text= 'Input data address') 
lbl1_Tab1.grid(column=0, row=0)  



def combo3_Tab1_click(event):
    global X # Setting select_sheet to global, so it can be modified
    X = combo3_Tab1.get()
    return X


def clicked_btn2_Tab1():

  X = combo3_Tab1_click(event)     
  return 0

combo3_Tab1 = Combobox(tab1, state="readonly")  
# combo3_Tab1.current(1) 
combo3_Tab1['values']= ["1","2","3"]
combo3_Tab1.grid(column=1, row=4) 
combo3_Tab1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", combo3_Tab1_click)

btn2_Tab1 = Button(tab1,text='Run CNN', command=clicked_btn2_Tab1)
btn2_Tab1.grid(column=0,row=7)

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')     

window.geometry('900x500')
 
window.mainloop()
```

How can I fixed this error
Thank you

Comment: Maybe you meant `clicked_btn2_Tab1(event):`?

Comment: Did you mean to use: `btn2_Tab1.bind(...` instead of `command=...`?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: Where do you expect the `event` to be defined?

Comment: @quamrana Take my comment as an incomplete solution, completed by your comment.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: Your first comment just seemed to simply introduce another problem.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, without your first comment.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana                                                                                                       
line 50, in clicked_btn2_Tab1
    X = combo3_Tab1_click(event)
NameError: name 'event' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Your `btn2_Tab1` is defined with a `command=` parameter which correctly calls the intended function.

Why does this function then need to call another that is intended to be the target for a `bind()` (which supplies the correct `event`)?

Just copy and paste the function contents:

```py
def clicked_btn2_Tab1():

  X = combo3_Tab1.get()     
  return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with below command:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
from scipy.stats import norm



font = FontProperties()
font.set_family('serif')
font.set_name('Times New Roman')
font.set_style('normal')  

    
window = Tk()
 
window.title("CCE Tool")
 
tab_control = Notebook(window) 

tab1 = Frame(tab_control) 
tab2 = Frame(tab_control)
 
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Regional') 
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Plot')

Filee_Tab1=Entry(tab1 ,width=70 , text='Enter adress of database')
Filee_Tab1.grid(column=1, row=0) 
 
lbl1_Tab1 = Label(tab1, text= 'Input data address') 
lbl1_Tab1.grid(column=0, row=0)  



def combo3_Tab1_click(event):
    global X # Setting select_sheet to global, so it can be modified
    X = combo3_Tab1.get()
    return X


def clicked_btn2_Tab1(event):

  X = combo3_Tab1_click(event)   
  print("OK")  
  return 0

combo3_Tab1 = Combobox(tab1, state="readonly")  
# combo3_Tab1.current(1) 
combo3_Tab1['values']= ["1","2","3"]
combo3_Tab1.grid(column=1, row=4) 
combo3_Tab1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", combo3_Tab1_click)

btn2_Tab1 = Button(tab1,text='Run CNN')
btn2_Tab1.grid(column=0,row=7)
btn2_Tab1.bind("<Button-1>", clicked_btn2_Tab1)

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')     

window.geometry('900x500')
 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: While this works, you will lose the built-in feature of tkinter that allows you to use the keyboard to traverse widgets and click on buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have created a function you want to be callable both from an event being handled, and from other places in the code. When you use `bind`, the function automatically gets a parameter we typically name `event`. However, when you call functions via a `command` attribute you don't get this parameter.

In your case, the simplest solution is to just pass `None` as the event parameter since the function doesn't use it

```
def clicked_btn2_Tab1():
  X = combo3_Tab1_click(event=None)     
  return 0
```

Another solution is to make the `event` parameter optional, so you can directly call it without the parameter:

```
def combo3_Tab1_click(event=None):
    ...
```